# Getting original date time from EXIF

Tags: c#, metadata-extractor

I'm trying to get the date of creation of a picture with this code :

```
private void GetEXIFDate()
        {
            var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(@"\\s2.rpn.ch\home\CPLN\Eleves\ET\CamiloDLe\My Pictures\Temp.jpg");
            var subIfdDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
            var dateTime = subIfdDirectory?.GetDateTime(ExifDirectoryBase.TagDateTime);
            MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToString());
        }
```

The MessageBox shows null and when i try to see the EXIF from windows i can see the modifiedDate and the date of creation.

I'm using .net 5.0 and MetadataExtractor to make this

Edit :
I was searching the wrong informations, I'd have the same informations that windows give, I want the EXIF informations instead.

Comment: Could you check source image has the date of creation?

Comment: I can find it, that's why i don't understand why my method can't

Comment: the given path for ReadMetadata is valid? could you sure that directories is not null?

Comment: I checked if the given path is right and i tried with different pictures and its the same result

Comment: Could you give more info about your development env, such as the version of .net, the library of Image?

Comment: Maybe the picture contains multiple exif sections.

Comment: I'm using .net 5.0 and I use metadata-extractor @KennetsuRinn

Comment: Even if i show every exif sections it doesn't show the date of creation @shingo

Comment: So what you want is the file's modified and creation date, not exif's ...

Comment: It would help if you told us where the library is from that you used (I had to google it). (OK, it's in the tag info, never mind. ) I also wonder why you didn't simply follow the basic test in the [Readme](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/blob/master/README.md): `IEnumerable<Directory> directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(imagePath); foreach (var directory in directories)
foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
    Console.WriteLine($"{directory.Name} - {tag.Name} = {tag.Description}");` first? That is, simply enumerate everything and see what's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using FileMetadataDirectory instead of ExifSubIfdDirectory
- Using random jpg from [output-onlinejpgtools.jpg](https://onlinejpgtools.com/generate-random-jpg)

```
using MetadataExtractor;
using MetadataExtractor.Formats.Exif;
using MetadataExtractor.Formats.FileSystem;
using MetadataExtractor.Formats.FileType;

var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(@"C:\Users\username\Pictures\output-onlinejpgtools.jpg");
var metadataDirectory = directories.OfType<FileMetadataDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(metadataDirectory.GetDateTime(3));
```

Comment: `FileMetadataDirectory` will give you the timestamp of the file on the filesystem, which may not be the time at which the image was initially captured. The best way to approach this is to list out all the metadata in your images in order to see what values exist that you could work with.